# How I can locate element depend on it value?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, specflow

I have some table:

```
    Title 1        | Title 2        | Title 3        |
    --------------------------------------------------
    string value 1 | string value 2 | string value 3 |
    --------------------------------------------------
    string value 4 | string value 5 | string value 6 |
```

and some step:
"And click on its < name>", where < name> can be anything from first column.

So, how I can found needed element and click on its?

Table code

```
<div id="grid" class="k-grid k-widget" data-role="grid" tabindex="0" style="">
<div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 17px;">
<div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
<table cellspacing="0">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 30px;">
<col style="width: 300px;">
<col>
<col style="width: 200px;">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="k-header" data-title="ID" data-field="id">ID</th>
<th class="k-header" data-title="Наименование" data-field="name" data-role="sortable" data-dir="asc">
<a class="k-link" href="#">
```

2nd part

```
Наименование
<span class="k-icon k-arrow-up"></span>
</a>
</th>
<th class="k-header" data-title="Описание" data-field="description">Описание</th>
<th class="k-header" data-field="undefined" data-role="sortable">
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

3rd part

```
    <div class="k-grid-content">
<table class="k-focusable k-selectable" cellspacing="0" data-role="selectable">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 30px;">
<col style="width: 300px;">
<col>
<col style="width: 200px;">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr data-uid="72c59bdf-8622-43c6-91bf-7a2a05ca59b1">
<td>5</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>
</tr>
```

4th part

```
<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="f8d1ef8c-07b0-4e79-9c42-4c6db2d943d0">
<td>6</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr data-uid="241a4a4b-7147-46fe-ad55-f865de4a8285">
<td>8</td>
<td>789</td>
<td>987</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="73bf8ea7-c4f0-49f9-8e8b-41d88b13212d">
<td>7</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>
</tr>
```

5th

```
<tr data-uid="63db0ec1-5a5a-40be-9fa0-b467ff2b43d3">
<td>4</td>
<td>Второй процесс</td>
<td>null</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr class="k-alt" data-uid="68fe2d62-5ccb-472b-b7b9-8ee95159deff">
<td>1</td>
<td>Заявление1</td>
<td>управление заявлениями</td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

6th

```
<div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager" data-role="pager">
<ul class="k-pager k-reset k-numeric">
<li>
<span class="k-state-active">1</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You question is awfully vague. Try improving it if you expect any answers.

Comment: It will help if you can post the code of your table.

Comment: @Bigfellahull What is not clear in the question?

Comment: I belive he meant HTML code, not the Code ID and cyrillics you added :D

Comment: @Zoltán Ofcourse I added the html code. Initially inserted incorrectly.

Comment: @NikolayKulakov It's vague because even with the HTML you posted, I have no idea what you are trying to do. Do you simply want to capture what elements are clicked on?

Comment: @Bigfellahull I want to select an element based on its value and then click on it. For example, in colunm 'Name' can be three rows with different names - Ann, Jim, Mike. The order is random, so Mike can be in 1st row and in other case he can be in 3rd row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partly understood what you are trying to do. You want to click on elements on your page based on the text values. To do this you will have to find elements on the page with the text you want to click on. For example - If you want to click on some element with the text = "Mike"
Use the following code -

```
WebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Name("Mike"));
```

Now you will get an WebElement to click on with the text "Mike".

So now - `ele.click();`

Another thing I want to mention is that your HTML code is not well formed(i.e does not have proper opening and closing tags). Having a well formed HTML will make interacting with elements on your web page easier when using selenium.